# Nautilus shortcut for mounting gdocs?

Tags: mount, nautilus, shortcuts, google, fuse

So I have this:

```
alias gdox='google-drive-ocamlfuse -m ~/Documents/myUserId@GDocs'
```

Is there a way to make a shortcut (or something else) in Nautilus so that I can see the above and access it by clicking? I note that in 
~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks I currently have these examples:

```
file:///usr/share/applications System *.desktop fls
sftp://host/home/username Laptop
```

So in theory there might be a URL that I can use to access my gdocs. 
I do understand that in one case you are mounting and in the other you are remotely accessing without mounting. How isn't so important to me as being able to get it into the Nautilus UI.

Comment: I just tried creating /media/user/GDocs and tried mounting there but it makes Nautilus start up dog slow for the likely reason that it has to hit Google to get a file listing before it can complete startup.   ...and it still doesn't show up in Nautilus, so double fail.

Comment: I don't know how to insert that into Nautilus, but you could also just make a one-line bash script with that mount command and put it on your desktop or into the launcher.